# issue in using ngfor, Error : No directive is matched on attribute ngFor Angular 14 used

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

```
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
     <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.emailId }}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

im using ngfor But Error sshowing like No directive is matched on attribute ngFor

Answer (score 5):

Please import CommonModule inside your custom module. After that include it inside the imports array.

```js
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

imports: [
  CommonModule
]
```

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: i used it brother

Comment: @Thushankavinda can you please update your question with the error?

Comment: No directive is matched on attribute ngFor. need to make this one. Watch code I used ngFor but showing weak warnings

Answer (score 1):

import {NgForOf} from "@angular/common";

in your component.ts file,
works for Angular 17

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need import `CommonModule` into your module, or component if you are using v14 standalone components. Share a stackblitz example of the error to better understand.

Comment: wait and I will update you now

Comment: `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. After importing **CommonModule** If it doesn't work after doing that, then check the **CORS** policy. Give Access to **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080`

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"